# How to change the CSS for an alert button in ionic 5?

Tags: ionic4

[image]

Referring to the picture, I want change the "No" to color red, Have put the css in app.component.css, variables.css and golbel.css, but noting changes. Hope that some one will help me.

Below is my alert code.

```js
async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
        header   : 'Logout',
        message  : 'Are you sure you want to logout?',
        buttons: [
            { text     : 'No',
              role     : 'cancel',
              cssClass : 'danger',
              handler: () => {
                  console.log('Confirm Logout: ok');
              }
            },
            { text    : 'Yes',
              handler: () => {
                  this.docDataMgr.logout();
                  this.router.navigate(['login']);
                  console.log('Confirm Okay');
              }
            }
        ]
    });
    await alert.present();
}
```

CSS code:

```
.danger  {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.alert-button` inside **global.scss**

Here you can use [first-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) and [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

```
 .alert-wrapper { 
    .alert-button:first-child {
      color: red;
    }
  }
```

For example:

[image]

**home.page.ts**

```
  async presentAlertMultipleButtons() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Alert Example',
      message: 'About Example data',
      buttons: ['Cancel', 'Delete']
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. let say if I have  nth-child(3), how do i use the  nth-child(3) css in an other the ionic page.

Comment: @JaredTiLianEng In that case you can use `::ng-deep` or `:host` before `.alert-wrapper` class inside you component's CSS. For example in home.page.scss you can use `::ng-deep {
.alert-wrapper { 
  .alert-button:first-child {
    color: green;
  }
 }
}`